# Kafka java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have installed kafka on vm and trying java program to connect to it and post data to  a topic but getting an error
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

I have done setting in server.properties and configured advertized.host.name to localhost.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through console producer?